# Camera and location permission at runtime in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a Xamarin forms application and it requires two permission i.e i)Location and ii)Camera.
I need to get both permissions at runtime but unfortunately I am able to get only one permission at a time when app starts.

Is there any solution to request both permission simultaneously at runtime.

Comment: Hi! It's a good advice to ask for permission when the application needs it, and not when the application starts. Also, how are you checking and asking for permissions? Are you using [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions)?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. and I am not using Permission feature of Xamarin.Essentials
I requested permission at runtime from Android project

Answer (score 4):

It's a good advice not to ask for permissions when the application starts, just  because the user might not know what is it for.

Also check and ask for permission when you need it. For example, ask for Camera permission just before opening the camera.

You can do all this using [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/). If your project does not have it, follow the documentation instructions to set it up.

And then you can do everything in your shared code (for all platforms!)

There are tons of examples, I will write one. You can ask for the permissions one after the other, or in two different moments

```
public async void GoToCameraPage()
        {
            var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                //We have permission!
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new CameraPage());
            }
            else
            {
                //Let the user know why
                await DisplayAlert("Permission needed", "I will need Camera permission for this action", "Ok");
                //Ask for the permission
                status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
                if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                    //YES, now we have permission
                }
                else
                {
                    //Ok, maybe I will ask again
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I got my answer from here-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/590593/camera-and-location-permission-at-runtime-in-xamar.html